# Equivalent to rspec =~ for arrays in Chai

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, chai

Does Chai, matchers have an equilivent to rspecs `=~` (which means has all elements but order doesn't matter.

#### Passing example

```
[1, 2, 3].should =~ [2, 1, 3]
```

#### Failing

```
[1, 2, 3].should =~ [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `members` test that is available in the latest Chai version:

```
expect([4, 2]).to.have.members([2, 4]);
expect([5, 2]).to.not.have.members([5, 2, 1]);
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is, but you can create one easily by [building a helper](http://chaijs.com/guide/helpers/):

```
var chai = require('chai'),
    expect = chai.expect,
    assert = chai.assert,
    Assertion = chai.Assertion

Assertion.addMethod('equalAsSets', function (otherArray) {
    var array = this._obj;

    expect(array).to.be.an.instanceOf(Array);
    expect(otherArray).to.be.an.instanceOf(Array);

    var diff = array.filter(function(i) {return !(otherArray.indexOf(i) > -1);});

    this.assert(
        diff.length === 0,
        "expected #{this} to be equal to #{exp} (as sets, i.e. no order)",
        array,
        otherArray
    );
});

expect([1,2,3]).to.be.equalAsSets([1,3,2]);
expect([1,2,3]).to.be.equalAsSets([3,2]);


flag
```

**Be aware** that this isn't an unordered equality test, it is set equality. Duplicate items are permitted in either array; this passes, for instance: `expect([1,2,3]).to.be.equalAsSets([1,3,2,2]);`

Comment: Note that the name for the method isn't really great, it is late and I didn't come up with anything better ;)

Comment: Be aware that this isn't an unordered equality test, it is _set_ equality. Duplicate items are permitted in either array; this passes, for instance: `expect([1,2,3]).to.be.equalAsSets([1,3,2,2]);`

Answer (score 0):

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/frames#Collection_membership

```
expect([4, 2]).to match_array([2, 4])
```